# Databind Repeater based on value in column

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am using microsoft sql server 2005 & have a drop down list databound to a table with a few records. On the selected index change of the drop down list, I want my repeater to re-databind only displaying records that have the same ID as the selected value in the drop down list.

Here is my drop down list:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlViewLabel" runat="server" Width="280px" 
 DataSourceID="sdsLabels" DataTextField="LabelName" DataValueField="LabelID" 
 onselectedindexchanged="ddlViewLabel_SelectedIndexChanged">
</asp:DropDownList>
```

Here is my repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDocuments" runat="server" OnItemCommand="viewDocument_ItemCommand"
 DataSourceID="sdsDocuments">
 <HeaderTemplate>
 </HeaderTemplate>
 <ItemTemplate>
  <div class="nav-rpt">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDocumentTitle" Text='<%# Bind("DocumentTitle") %>' runat="server"
                            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DocumentID") %>' CssClass="nav-rpt-btn"></asp:LinkButton>
   <img src="Images/ARROW.png" style="float: right" />
  </div>
 </ItemTemplate>
 <SeparatorTemplate>
  <div style="border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-color: #C0C0C0;">
  </div>
 </SeparatorTemplate>
 <FooterTemplate>
   <div style="border-top-style: solid; border-top-width: 1px; border-top-color: #C0C0C0;">
   </div>
 </FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Here are my 2 data sources:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsDocuments" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:blcDocumentationConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [DocumentID], [DocumentTitle], [DocumentBody], [ModifiedDate], [CreatedDate] FROM [tblDocument]">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsLabels" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:blcDocumentationConnectionString %>"
            SelectCommand="SELECT [LabelID], [LabelName] FROM [tblLabel]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsLink" runat="server" 
  ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:blcDocumentationConnectionString %>" 
  SelectCommand="SELECT [LabelID], [DocumentID], [LinkID] FROM [tblLink]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Where do I enter logic to filter the repeater from displaying 'Documents' with the correct 'LabelID' ?

Comment: do you have labelId in tblDocuments as foreign key ?

Comment: Sorry Muhammad, left out part of my question. Please look @ my changes. I have a 'Link' table which links each document with its correct label.

Comment: If the row count isn't too big, you could just show/hide rows with jQuery or JavaScript whenever the dropdownlist changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write some code for your defined ddlViewLabel_SelectedIndexChanged method on the dropdownlist

```
protected void ddlViewLabel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
DropDownList d = (DropDownList)sender;

// psudeo code from here on out
// get the DropDownList selected index
// create the new SQL statement
// either create a new SQlDataSource or SqlCommand/SqlConnection objects, set the sql, attach them to the repeater, bind

}
```

Comment: How do i attach them to the repeater?

Comment: repeater.DataSource = <whatever>